# Заменить чем-то или на что-то?

Tags: лексика

Интересно, "заменить чем-то" и "заменить на что-то" — равнозначные выражения или все-таки отличаются оттенками смысла? Как вы думаете?

Comment: Такой же вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31618/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я думаю, что стилистически правильно будет "заменить что-то чем-то" и "поменять что-то на что-то". 
Других сколько-нибудь существенных отличий не вижу.
Субъективно скажу скорее "заменить перепелиные яйца куриными" (в кулинарном рецепте, в случае отсутствия первых) и "***поменять*** компьютер на планшет" (просто в силу морального устаревания). Строго сформулировать не могу.

Comment: Все верно.  Только можно в обоих случаях использовать глагол заменить. Словарь сочетаемости дает эти случаи употребления как синонимичные.

Comment: Ларf, я не утверждал обратного. 
Тут что-то другое...  
Замена "что-то на что-то" предполагает какую равноценную замену или даже улучшенную.  
А "что-то чем-то" скорее какую-то вынужденную или неравноценную. И вот в этом случае "поменять" уже как-то не смотрится. Только "заменить". 
Как-то так. Я сказал, что не могу пока четко сформулировать.