# Заменить чем-то или на что-то? (2)

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно сказать: заменить *чем-то* или *на что-то*? Или эти слова равнозначны?

Comment: Такой же вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/25388/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ зависит от словаря. Грамота.ру, ссылаясь, видимо, на "Толковый словарь" Кузнецова и на "Управление в русском языке" Розенталя, отвечала так: заменить что-то чем-то, поменять что-то на что-то. Розенталь писал: "Под влиянием конструкции *сменить что на что* встречается ненормативное употребление оборота *заменить что на что*". Но "Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка", изданный в 2005 г. Государственным институтом русского языка им. А. С. Пушкина, признает нормативными оба варианта (в случае неодушевленности): заменить кого-что-либо кем-чем и заменить что-либо на что. Решайте сами, кто для вас авторитет.

Comment: Мне тоже больше нравится "заменить чем". Но этот вариант в СМИ и живой речи практически не встречается. Видимо, придется смириться с мнением большинства, а самой говорить так, как мне нравится.

Answer (score 2):

Грамота.ру дает единственный вариант "заменить кого-что чем", а этот портал, как мне кажется, обычно выражает официальную позицию. Достаточно вспомнить, как быстро они стали писать "миллионноголосый" вместо "миллионоголосый".

Думаю, что вариант  "заменить чем" в современной речи поддерживается именно ВОПРОСОМ - мы чаще говорим "чем это можно заменить", чем "на что  это можно заменить". Соответственно, выражение "заменить чем" кажется более грамотным, хотелось бы его оставить.